How to filter out noise from systemd-journald
I get quite a lot of noise in systemd-journald. These are messages that I expect (logins from a monitoring system for instance) that I would like to filter out before journald store them. Is this possible?
Notes:

This is not a question about filtering journalctl queries (there is a question about that)
I realize it would be best to send out logs to a log manager and filter out on egress over there but I do not have one (yet)


It seems you are asking about 'how to do not_store/drop some system messages', isn't it? or are there some other ideas/conditions

@TomNewton yes, exactly, how to drop some messages before they are stored

When the logs come from a systemd unit, you can use LogFilterPatterns in unit configs.
More info, https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.exec.html
